# python matplotlib: fast updating of a single point in a scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a large scatter, say 100k points.
I want to animate it by enlarging a single point at each time-stamp so a trail will be seen.
FuncAnimation is great for updating scatter plots, however it updates the entire scatter, so once again slow at this scale.
Is there a way to get fast performance since i only wish to update a single point at each time?

Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_points = 1000
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()

data = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,2))

scat_hndlrs = []

for d in data:
    scat_hndlrs.append(plt.scatter(*d, s=10))

for i in range(1,num_points):
    scat_hndlrs[i]._sizes=[80]
    scat_hndlrs[i-1]._sizes=[10]
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Does `blit=True` help in the input to FuncAnimation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to only create one scatter plot, rather than a plot instance per point and then use the animation module to modify the sizes of the PathCollection returned by plt.scatter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

num_points = 1000
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,2))
data_t = data.T
sizes = np.ones(num_points)*10
scat_handler = plt.scatter(data_t[0], data_t[1], s=sizes)


def animate_blit(i):
    sizes = scat_handler.get_sizes()
    sizes[i] = 50
    sizes[(i - 1) % num_points] = 10
    scat_handler.set_sizes(sizes)
    return scat_handler,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_blit, num_points, blit=True, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Niemerds, that's better, but not there yet. Could it be because of the re-declaration of sz_arr inside animate: `sz_arr = np.ones(num_points)*10`. Is there a way to pass it?

Comment: Yes, there is (see modified example). I also added blitting, but 100k points is probably too much to ask for. It works for me for ~ 10k points.

Comment: I would not rely on `get_sizes()` returning a ref to the underlying data.  I would use `set_sizes`.

Comment: Even better guys, thanks. You also helped me realize that even though my process runs on 100k points (or even more), there is no need to display them all. I'll sample a representative set, and work with that. Thanks again

Comment: (my points are with color) One more thing that i noticed is that disabling `edgecolors` runs few times faster than when its enabled. Can you approve this observation?